# customizing the form title bar in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to know how can I customize the title bar of the form in visual basic. Like in Internet Explorer, the Back and forward buttons, the search bar and the tabs are located in the title bar.
Please help me.

Comment: No they are not in "title bar" but on a separate "tool bar". And are you talking about VBA or VB?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to hide the default title bar and create your own custom one to replace it. I don't think that sort of style is out the box.

This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/574255/2440747